# Does OrientDB allow multiple edges for one or more vertex?

Tags: nosql, graph-databases, orientdb

I tried searching on this, but could not find any simple answer.  Based on a image in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/GraphDatabase) it seems like it does, but I am not sure.

What I am talking about are examples like this:

Example 1:  One Property

```
A --> B --> C
Property 1: Knows
```

**B "Knows" A and C.**

Example 2:  Multiple Properties

```
 A --> B 
(I am not sure how to show multiple properties here)
Property 1: Knows
Property 2: Friends
```

**A is "Friends" with B and A "Knows" B**

Also is there some way to introduce Hierarchy.
If A is "Friends" with "B" than A ***implicitly*** also "Knows" B.

A general yes or no would be enough.  If there is some example or link that you can provide that has more explanation that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Course you can. OrientDB has 3 Graph API. One of these is the TinkerPop Blueprints API that are highly documented: http://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki

To create 2 edges:

```
Vertex luca = graph.addVertex(null);
luca.setProperty( "name", "Luca" );

Vertex marko = graph.addVertex(null);
marko.setProperty( "name", "Marko" );

Edge lucaKnowsMarko = graph.addEdge(null, luca, marko, "knows");

Vertex jay = graph.addVertex(null);
marko.setProperty( "name", "Jay" );

Edge lucaRespectsJay = graph.addEdge(null, luca, jay, "respects");
```

Lvc@

Comment: Thanks for OrientDB. I am not sure if I am writing this correctly, but could you also have `Edge lucaRespectsMarko = graph.addEdge(null, luca, marko, "respects");` (adding another Edge between luca and Marco). Any comments on the **Hierarchy** question.

Comment: Thanks again @Lvca.  **Any comments on the Hierarchy question.**